# Problem with upload images openstack

Tags: juju, maas, openstack

I'm working with MAAS and juju. And I use 6 nodes for Openstack.
Everything goes good! But when I try to upload ubuntu-cloud-image there are errors.

```
Thu Sep 26 09:43:43 UTC 2013: ====== extracting image ======
Warning: no ramdisk found, assuming '--ramdisk none'
kernel : oneiric-server-cloudimg-amd64-vmlinuz-virtual
ramdisk: none
image  : oneiric-server-cloudimg-amd64.img
Thu Sep 26 09:44:01 UTC 2013: ====== bundle/upload kernel ======
failed to upload bundle to images/oneiric-server-cloudimg-amd64-vmlinuz-virtual.manifest.xml
failed: euca-upload-bundle --bucket images --manifest /tmp/cloud-publish-image.reLvSN/oneiric-server-cloudimg-amd64-vmlinuz-virtual.manifest.xml
S3_URL not specified.  Trying http://localhost:8773/services/Walrus
Checking bucket: images
[Errno 111] Connection refusedfailed to upload kernel
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Could you run the same with `--debug -v` switches? Also, have you enabled the firewall?

Comment: i think firewall is enabled)))

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at my answer in [Openstack on MAAS error when upload images](https://askubuntu.com/questions/351796/openstack-on-maas-error-when-upload-images) for details on how to upload Ubuntu Cloud Images to an OpenStack cloud.