# Openstack on MAAS error when upload images

Tags: openstack

```
ubuntu@node-4:~/openstack$ cloud-publish-tarball ./ubuntu-12.04-beta1-server-cloudimg->amd64.tar.gz images
Mon Sep 30 09:18:20 UTC 2013: ====== extracting image ======
Warning: no ramdisk found, assuming '--ramdisk none'
kernel : precise-server-cloudimg-amd64-vmlinuz-virtual
ramdisk: none
image  : precise-server-cloudimg-amd64.img
Mon Sep 30 09:18:36 UTC 2013: ====== bundle/upload kernel ======
failed to upload bundle to images/precise-server-cloudimg-amd64-vmlinuz-virtual.manifest.xml
failed: euca-upload-bundle --bucket images --manifest /tmp/cloud-publish-image.eRhmYU/precise-server-cloudimg-amd64-vmlinuz-virtual.manifest.xml
S3_URL not specified.  Trying http://localhost:8773/services/Walrus
Checking bucket: images
[Errno 111] Connection refusedfailed to upload kernel
```

how to fix it?

Comment: Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

I've never used cloud-publish-tarball; I generally use the glance CLI tools directly to create images in OpenStack:

```
glance image-create --name ubuntu-12.04 --file precise-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk1.img --is-public True --disk-format qcow2 --container-format bare --property architecture=x86_64
```

The -disk1.img files from cloud-images.ubuntu.com are bootable on OpenStack without providing a separate kernel/initrd etc...